# Cannot get GSAP to navigate timeline with my functions

Tags: jquery, html, css, gsap

I am trying to achieve a greensock animated banner that I can navigate around to different scenes.

Using their API documentation I have gotten as far as setting up the timeline so each scene has an intro and outro animation, but for some reason when I start adding click event handlers nothing happen and no alerts are sent.

Please have a look at my code pen [HERE](http://codepen.io/Caderial/pen/LbYRVZ/)

I have set up a miain timeline that plays through each trainsition for each scene in and out, I have added pauses after each scenes intro and labels for intro and outro in each scene.

The goal here is to have the initial intro animation slide in, and when clicking on the NYBtn call the function I've written at the bottom of the js file to trigger the timeline to play from the label 'NYSceneIntro'

```
$("#NYBtn").click(function() {
alert('Clicked NY!');
tlSlideMain.play(NYSceneIntro);
});
```

Ideally I would have one of these functions to animate in each Slide depending on which button is clicked:

NYBtn -> NYSlideIntro

NJBtn -> NJSlideIntro

PABtn -> PASlideIntro

etc...
Am I missing something? or just coding wrong? Keep in mind I am completely new to jquery and gsap

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had used the wrong addPause function in my timeline and therefore it was breaking. I have updated the codepen to reflect this. I now have the transitions loading appropriately.